# Is there a way to get the ip address from given url in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ip-address

Given a URL like: `https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRM/googlechrome.dmg`,
how can I get the IP address, e.g., `74.125.224.140`, in the Cocoa framework or with an Objective-C method?

Answer (score 4):

try this. I think that is what you expecting.

1. It will convert string to url.
2. From this url you can get domain name.
3. From domain name you can get address as given below.

   ```
   NSURL *validURL = [NSURL URLWithString: yourUrl];
   NSString *host = [validURL host];
   NSString *ipAdress = [[NSHost hostWithName:host]address];
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *ip = [[NSHost hostWithName:(NSString *)yourDomainNameUrl] address];
```

Comment: btw: perhaps you'll need to modify the url. It should look like this: "dl.google.com".

Comment: No need to “modify the URL”, but you do need to extract the hostname. You can do that by creating an NSURL object with the URL and then asking it for the host.

Comment: Beware that [using NSHost is dangerous](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-13-dangerous-cocoa-calls.html).

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I just want to get the URL's ip by using BSD ipfw for Bandwidth throttling,but google have lots ip,it does not work for me.I need to control the Bandwidth throttling in another way.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
#import <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    struct hostent *host_entry = gethostbyname(charUrl);
    char *buff = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));
});
```

Thanks to: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726738/determining-ip-address-from-url-in-ios)