# How to get current request connect server ip addres

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the current request's connect server IP address when I use `NSURLSession`.
What are the methods available？

I am trying to use

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didFinishCollectingMetrics:(NSURLSessionTaskMetrics *)metrics
```

but it doesn’t seem to have the target IP address.

Supplement for [How can I get the exactly ip address which used to connect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508871/how-can-i-get-the-exactly-ip-address-which-used-to-connect-in-ios])：

My demand is to monitor network performance in an existing project ，so not be able to replace `NSURLsesion` with `CFNetwork`.
Or can anyone tell me how to **hook** or **use** the lower level direction?

Thanks in advance ！

Comment: More like you need NSURL to IP address translation? If so you have to go low level and use CFNetServiceGetAddressing.

Comment: @MarekH thanks for your answer，but What I need to get is the IP used by the **current request** and I can't do HTTPDNS. Because DNS can correspond to multiple IPs, simple transitions can't meet demand.

Comment: In this case you need to go lower level and use CFNetwork. This can't be done using NSURLSession

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508871/how-can-i-get-the-exactly-ip-address-which-used-to-connect-in-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the exactly ip address which used to connect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508871/how-can-i-get-the-exactly-ip-address-which-used-to-connect-in-ios)

Comment: @MarekH The goal of getting IP is consistent with it, and the difference has been added. Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: If you want to try search github.com for mentioned functions of cfnetwork. Asking on stackoverflow you are required to show some coding effort. People don't like to see what you just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have collected this data in

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didFinishCollectingMetrics:(NSURLSessionTaskMetrics *)metric
```

Unfortunately, it is a private api.

code is:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_timingData");

NSDictionary *timingData = nil;
if ([task respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    timingData = [task performSelector:selector];
}
NSString *remoteServerIP = @"";
if (timingData && [timingData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSString *key = @"_kCFNTimingDataRemoteAddressAndPort";
    remoteServerIP = timingData[key];
}
```

Comment: Your answer is great! In iOS 13+, seems like they have a way to do this in one line now (still private API AFAIK though): https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/f1618b20c06ce81c30f4d2913338d74d52962b89/Source/WebKit/NetworkProcess/cocoa/NetworkTaskCocoa.mm#L85