# Can I add a local DNS entry in iOS?

Tags: ios, rest, https, dns, bonjour

I have following case :

[image: device]

The HW device has a restFul service which runs https. The certificate is signed by an authorized CA and has the domain **my-device.mydomain.com**. The device has a WiFi hotspot which the iOS device connects to. I now need an app on the iOS device to talk to this restFul service. In the app I can detect this HW device by bonjour so I can construct the url being https://my-device.mydomain.com but since I do not have a DNS how can i tell the iOS device that host my-device.mydomain.com is x.x.x.x. I presume I need that otherwise I would not be able to talk to the service using HTTPS. My guess that adding things to HOSTST file is a no go since one does not have access to the underlaying files of iOS. Maybe there is no problem at all but I just want to make sure I haven't missed something.

/donnib

Comment: Maybe this link helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726738/determining-ip-address-from-url-in-ios

Comment: I don't think that solve the issue i think i have. I have the ip, i have the url. I need to talk to the rest service over the URL and iOS cannot resolv the ip of the url since there is no dns in the network that can resolve it.

Comment: You may know better as RestAPIs are not my area. Does this link resolve your issue? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/resolving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002487-SW1

Comment: No it doesn't sorry.